# Create a callback loop with CoffeeScript's classes and jquery.transit

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, coffeescript, transition

With jquery.transit I want to build a loop by using jquery.transit's callback parameter. I do not want to use `setTimeout()` to avoid possible race conditions.

The following code works: http://jsfiddle.net/2errn/

```
$ ->
  animate = () ->
    console.log "animate()"
    $(".rect").transition({x: 10}, animate)
  animate()
```

The rectangular only moves one time, but in the console it's clear that the method is entered multiple times. So this works! To make it move more often I would need to add an increment counter to the x-coordinate, but that's not the issue here.

I wanted to encapsulate the functionality in a class and here it fails: http://jsfiddle.net/6A97m/1/

```
$ ->
  class Animator
    animate: ->
      console.log "animate()"
      $(".rect").transition({x: 10}, @animate)

    new Animator().animate()
```

The function is entered only two times before the output of the logging statement stops. Why is that? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply an unbound function reference:

```
@animate
```

That reference has no specific `@` bound to it so `@` will be chosen when it is called. In particular, `@` won't be your `Animator` instance so `@animate` will be `undefined` the second time you access it.

If you change your `console.log` to this:

```
console.log @, "animate()"
```

You'll see that `@` is your `Animator` instance the first time `animate` is called but it is something else the second time.

There are various solutions:

1. Use a [bound method](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow):

   ```
   animate: =>
     console.log "animate()"
     $(".rect").transition({x: 10}, @animate)
   ```

   Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/3puUe/
2. Bind `animate` when you pass it using [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

   ```
   animate: ->
     console.log "animate()"
     $(".rect").transition({x: 10}, @animate.bind(@))
   ```

   Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/BPSa9/
3. Manually set up the appropriate `@` using the old `_this = this` trick:

   ```
   animate: ->
     console.log "animate()"
     _this = @
     $(".rect").transition({x: 10}, -> _this.animate())
   ```

   Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/p4z8x/

Most toolkit libraries off their own binding methods in case you can't guarantee that `Function.bind` will be available: [`_.bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind), [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/), ...

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I didn't know that bound method using `=>` can be applied in this case here, too, but I start to understand. Thanks.